# Invoking concurrent AWS Batch jobs for a group of SQS messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-batch

I have millions of independent tasks in the SQS FIFO queue. Each task can take 1-3 minutes to get completed and needs to update status in RDS.

I want to take a batch of say 10,000 messages (tasks) and run it in an AWS batch job. I want to run all these batch jobs in parallel.

Common usage pattern I see:

#### Trigger lambda on a batch of messages and do processing in lambda itself

**Limitation:**

- max message batch size - 10
- partial batch failure handling  - need to delete successful messages of the batch or use dead letter queue.
- concurrent connection limit in RDS -  for 1 million message and batch size of 10, it requires 100,000 lambda invocations. Even with max 1000 concurrent lambda its a lot of RDS connections.

#### One way to invoke these concurrent batch jobs:

Start one master batch job and do long polling of messages. Once 10,000 messages are there, invoke a batch job and so on.

Is there a better way to deal with this?

Comment: The bottleneck in this case would be the RDS. While lambda is limited to 10 messages per batch, SQS can invoke those batches extremely fast and handling errors in batch of 10 is way easier. I would suggest, if possible, move data for this task from RDS to something scalable like Aurora serverless or DynamoDB.

Comment: @OleksiiDonoha thanks for the insights. Changing DB is not possible in my scenario.

Comment: Is the Amazon RDS connection required for the entire execution time of the Lambda function, or just for updating the status at the end?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein just at the end.

Comment: If the Lambda function establishes a connection with Amazon RDS only for the update process at the end, and then specifically disconnects afterwards, then the number of concurrent RDS connections would be quite small, since it is only used for a fraction of the 1-3 minutes.